# Is it possible to move fluent configuration of a hierarchy in a separate class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a hierarchy and I want to configure it in one class. Is it possible?

Currently I have `N` implementations for `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` interface - one per each entity in the hierarchy.

Comment: What do you mean by "hierarchy"? Base/derived entities (inheritance) or something else?

Comment: Exactly. Inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it is possible. After all, you are not forced to use `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` at all - you can configure *all* your entities inside `OnModelCreating`. Also all the `ApplyConfiguration` generic method does is to call `Configure` method of the class implementing the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` interface passing `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>` instance which you normally get from `modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()` call (or receive as an argument of the `Action<>` of the second overload of that method).

Hence you can put your code in any static or instance class method receiving the `ModelBuilder` instance. If you want to use class, it shouldn't implement `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` because there is no way to get `ModelBuilder` from ``EntityTypeBuilder`, and you need it in order to be able to configure both base and derived entities.

For instance, something like this:

```
class MyHierarchyConfiguration
{
    public void Apply(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyBaseEntity>(builder =>
        {
            // base entity configuration here
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyDerivedEntity1>(builder =>
        {
            // derived entity configuration here
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyDerivedEntity2>(builder =>
        {
            // derived entity configuration here
        });
        // etc.
    }
}
```

and inside `OnModelCreating`:

```
new MyHierarchyConfiguration().Apply(modelBuilder);
```

Comment: This is sure a working solution, but maybe it’s worth accepting `modelBuilder` in constructor and then wrapping it with class/interface exposing API which constraints the types just to hierarchy. On one hand it is an overkill, on the other hand it is a clear expression of intention - configuring the hierarchy.

Comment: Since it is encapsulating all the configuration code, I don't see how you can constrain it or provide API. In fact this approach is not constrained to hierarchies - it can be used to encapsulate fluent configuration of any set of (related) entities. If the intent is just to share common base configuration, then the solution is different - generic base configuration class (`MyEntityConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity`) and derived configuration classes for each derived entity inheriting it (to configure the specific aspects). But that's not "one class" solution.

Comment: And I didn't use constructor / class state because I wanted to indicate the stateless nature of the configuration - the `Apply` method can be made static, or the class could be made singleton. DI cannot be used to resolve `ModelBuilder` instance (it's an argument of `OnConfiguring`), so no real benefit of using constructor/state. Just a shared piece of code moved out from the `DbContext`.

Comment: But generic version allows us to define the base class. `abstract class ConfigureHierarcy<TBase>`. Implementors have to override `Configure` which accepts  “special” builder which constraints types of configured entities to inheritors of `TBase`.

Comment: Yes, it does. But note that it must be called with the *actual* class, in other words, for each derived class. It's more suitable for hierarchies which don't use EF inheritance - just base classes. If that's what you asked, the answer would be different - for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990365/entity-framework-core-2-0-how-to-configure-abstract-base-class-once/49997115#49997115

Comment: Just curious why would anyone need to configure the hierarchy without using EF inheritance capabilities:)

Comment: Because people use base classes just to share some common properties (like `DateCreated`, `DateModified`, `TenantId` etc., or even just `int Id`). They don't want polymorphic queries, also don't want to store their entities in a single table (what current EF Core does by supporting only TPH). But still they can write generic code against such entities, like `FindById` etc.

Comment: I see. But that's a kinda abuse of OOP due to the lack of structural typing and templating.

Comment: Agreed hundred percent. But it's what it is. And we use what we have (is given to us) by the language :)