# Issue with base class in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I have many classes looks like following:

```
public class ModelOneConfiguration
{
    public ModelOneConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<ModelOne> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnUpdate();
        entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired();         
        entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired();
    }

}
```

And call it from Db context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    new ModelOneConfiguration(builder.Entity<ModelOne>());
    ….other classes as well…
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);       
}
```

When I migrate it works fine with following results:

```
Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NEWID()"),
CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "getutcdate()"),
UpdatedAt = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true, defaultValueSql: "getutcdate()"),
FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
```

So far so Good.

Now I tried to wrap up Id, CreatedAt and UpdatedAt in base class so I can use it with all my other model configuration classes. So what I did, I was following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990365/entity-framework-core-2-0-how-to-configure-abstract-base-class-once) answered by Ivan Stoev.

So for my base class I did following

```
public class BaseConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntities
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()").ValueGeneratedOnUpdate();
    }
}
```

Then I extended my model configure class:

```
public class ModelOneConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<ModelOne>
{
    public ModelOneConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<ModelOne> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Now when I run migration It generate following

```
Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: false),
UpdatedAt = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
```

As we can see, `defaultValueSql: "NEWID()"`, `defaultValueSql: "getutcdate()"` are just missing in `Id`, `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt`.

And I am using Core 2.2 with EF core 2.2.

My Question is very simple:

What I am doing wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Is the `BaseConfiguration.Configure` method being called?

Comment: Is there a reason the configuration in the `ModelOneConfiguration` class is done in the constructor instead of overriding the `Configure` method?

Comment: no it is just because I have taken over an old code and was working on clean it up a bit so any suggestion are welcoming

Comment: In my experience, that is how it should be done, and perhaps why your code doesn't work. Move that code into the `Configure` method, and don't forget to call `base.Configure`

Comment: By the way Iwhile you asked in your first comment, It is not true I found out that the method was not called what i did I added  base.Configure(entity); and it worked, you are welcome to leave answer and any other suggestion I will accpeted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived class should be doing the work inside the `Configure` method, and not in the constructor. Add an `override` for that, and make sure to call the base `Configure` method:

```
public class ModelOneConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<ModelOne>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ModelOne> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired();
    }
}
```