# Entity Framework creating table hierarchy when I don't want to

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have two classes `SomeClass` and `SomeDerivedClass`:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    public string BaseField { get; set; }  
}

public class SomeOtherClass : SomeClass
{
     public string SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

However, no matter what I try, Entity Framework tries to model the hierarchy in the database. I don't want `SomeClass` to be considered at all in the schema, I just want `SomeOtherClass` to act as its own entirely separate entity.

I want a single table called `SomeOtherClass` with columns `Id`, `BaseField`, and `SomeField`. However, Entity Framework always tries to create a table called `SomeClass` with a discriminator column, or one table for each.

List of things I have tried:

- Calling `.ToTable("SomeOtherClass")` for both entities in `OnModelCreating`. Still adds a discriminator column. Tried adding `HasNoDiscriminator()`, but then I get the error

> All the entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be mapped to different tables`

- Calling `.ToView(null)` on `SomeClass` and `.ToTable("SomeOtherClass")` on `SomeOtherClass`. In this case the table loses the base columns (`BaseField`)
- Calling `.HasBaseType<SomeClass>` `.HasBaseType<SomeOtherClass >` on both, but then I get an error about invalid hierarchy.
- Making the base class `abstract` seems to have no effect.

How can I inherit a class in Entity Framework without it trying to make a hierarchy in the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997115/472966

I had another entity referring to `SomeClass` directly which made EF Core think it was an entity rather than just a class.