# Template to add in most Classes to create Migration Models with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

### Template to add in most Classes to create Migration Models with EF Core

With **DataAnnotations** there is **one point at Base Class to declare** using **Attributes**  *for example ...TypeName...*

```
Every Model which inherits from that BaseClass is scaffolded correct and all Attributes are taken
```

With **FluentAPI** you **have to declare Property attributes  *for example ...HasColumnTypes...* on each Model** you want to create.
Or **loop through** after ModelBuilder is finished or create a **Convention for ModelFinalizer**

```
Every Model inherited from BaseClass has to be modified manually/looped for each property, regardless of defining a Grouped SetupClass for that BaseClass
```

### How to use FluentAPI to get same results as DataAnnotation with a single Point of Definition ?

#### expected result

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [BlogsMS];

CREATE TABLE [LogEntries] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CreatedAt]  smalldatetime NOT NULL,    -- from DataAnnotations
    [UpdatedAt]  smalldatetime NOT NULL,    -- from FluentAPI with SingleConfigPoint ?   
);
```

### Source

#### template class

```cs
public abstract class DefaultAuditColumns
{
    [Column(TypeName = ("smalldatetime"))]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }  // DB Type defined with DataAnnotations
 
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }  // DB Type defined FluentAPI Grouped OnModelCreating  
}
```

#### first example class/entity

```
public class TableLogged : DefaultAuditColumns  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

#### second example class/entity

```
public class AnotherTableLogged : DefaultAuditColumns
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

#### Sql table results

```sql
  CREATE DATABASE [BlogsMS];

      CREATE TABLE [AnotherLogEntries] (
          [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [Description] nvarchar(200) NULL,
          [CreatedAt] smalldatetime NOT NULL,
          [UpdatedAt] datetime2 NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_AnotherLogEntries] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );

      CREATE TABLE [LogEntries] (
          [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [Description] nvarchar(200) NULL,
          [CreatedAt] smalldatetime NOT NULL,
          [UpdatedAt] datetime2 NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_LogEntries] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
```

### How to use FluentAPI to get same results as DataAnnotation with a single Point of Definition ?

The Suggestion [Entity Framework Core 2.0: How to configure abstract base class once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49990365/5265292) Ivan Stoev – grek40 does the job but

**Some of the Property Attributes then still are missing in scaffolded Model/Classes.**

**The Modified Class look now like, all works as expected :-)**

```
public  class TableLoggedConfiguration :  DefaultAuditColumnsConfiguration<TableLogged>, IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableLogged>
 {
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableLogged> entity)
     {
         base.Configure(entity); // <--
         // entity.Property(e => e.ReviewedAt).HasColumnType("smalldatetime");
         // entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(30);
         // entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(30);
         entity.Property(e => e.DecimalType).HasColumnType("decimal(18,5)").HasPrecision(18, 5);
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you use `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, have a look at this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49990365/5265292

Comment: @grek40  Thanks a lot this is exaclty what i was looking for. That save's a lot of time :-)

Comment: The Suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/q/49990365/5265292 @Ivan Stoev – grek40   does the job but

some of the Property Attributes are still missing in scaffolded Model/Classes.
For example the decimal property ...

The modified Class look now like  and all works as expected :-)